# Natural way of indexing elements in Flink

Tags: indexing, apache-flink, flink-streaming

Is there a built-in way to index and access indices of individual elements of *DataStream/DataSet* collection?

Like in typical Java collections, where you know that e.g. a 3rd element of an ArrayList can be obtained by `ArrayList.get(2)` and vice versa `ArrayList.indexOf(elem)` gives us the index of (the first occurence of) the specified element. (I'm not asking about extracting elements out of the stream.)

More specifically, when `join`ing *DataStreams/DataSets*, is there a "natural"/easy way to join elements that came (were created) first, second, etc.?

I know there is a [`zipWithIndex`](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/api/java/org/apache/flink/api/java/utils/DataSetUtils.html#zipWithIndex-org.apache.flink.api.java.DataSet-) transformation that assigns sequential indices to elements. I suspect the indices always start with 0? But I also suspect that they aren't necessarily assigned in the order the elements were created in (i.e. by their Event Time). (It also exists only for *DataSets*.)
This is what I currently tried:

```
DataSet<Tuple2<Long, Double>> tempsJoIndexed = DataSetUtils.zipWithIndex(tempsJo);
DataSet<Tuple2<Long, Double>> predsLinJoIndexed = DataSetUtils.zipWithIndex(predsLinJo);
DataSet<Tuple3<Double, Double, Double>> joinedTempsJo = tempsJoIndexed
                .join(predsLinJoIndexed).where(0).equalTo(0)...
```

And it seems to create wrong pairs.

I see some possible approaches, but they're either non-Flink or not very nice:

1. I could of course assign an index to each element upon the stream's
   creation and have e.g. a stream of `Tuple`s.
2. Work with event-time timestamps. (I suspect there isn't a way to key by timestamps, and even if there was, it wouldn't be useful for
   joining multiple streams like this unless the timestamps are
   actually assigned as indices.)
3. We could try "`collect`ing" the stream first but then we wouldn't be using Flink anymore.

The 1. approach seems like the most viable one, but it also seems redundant given that the stream should by definition be a sequential collection and as such, the elements should have a sense of orderliness (e.g. `I'm the 36th element because 35 elements already came before me.`).

Answer (score 1):

I think you're going to have to assign index values to elements, so that you can partition the data sets by this index, and thus ensure that two records which need to be joined are being processed by the same sub-task. Once you've done that, a simple `groupBy(index)` and `reduce()` would work.

But assigning increasing ids without gaps isn't trivial, if you want to be reading your source data with parallelism > 1. In that case I'd create a `RichMapFunction` that uses the runtimeContext sub-task id and number of sub-tasks to calculate non-overlapping and monotonic indexes.